# The basic pattern to implement a asynchronous logging

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

In my web application, we do some socket job in our servlet, and we log socket data into database.

I want to make that logging process asynchronous to improve performance.

My idea is using a separate dedicated thread to do the logging job. In my servlet, I just submit data to a cache, and let the logging thread to process them one by one.

I have a little experience in threading, What collection I can use as the cache ? What's the basic code pattern to implement this ? Please provide some code to show how to achieve that.

sorry for my poor English

As my application is legacy system running in production environment.It just use servlet and jsp no other Java EE technology. It seems that adding JMS support is too expensive for me.

Comment: Many existing logging frameworks handle this quite nicely, have you considered using [log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) (behind [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/))? Have a look at their [async loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)

Comment: @kuporific I know log4j 2, but our leader will not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

A queue and a thread pool should be good.Publish your messages on a queue, let the workers thread pick messages from the queue and save them in database. Depending on your requirement/load, you may tune your queue and thread pool size.

Comment: just a java.uti.Queue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to output the log to a single file, you could try using a Semaphore (preferably a Mutex) on the logger class to prevent simultaneous writes / a race condition. Semaphores are synchronization primitives designed so that the programmer can use them to ensure only a certain number of accesses can be made to any one data structure at any one time. I won't explain the whole concept but Java provides these things in the [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class. A mutex (**mut**ual **ex**clusion lock) is a semaphore that only allows one thread to be "hold" it at any given time. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at using a dedicated thread to handle the logging, you will want to implement a Producer/Consumer pattern, and use the Queue to handle the storing of the information objects.  The producer/consumer pattern is mostly used to help with thread synchronization and communication.   Here is an example of a Producer/Consumer implementation that might help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm

The other option, is to generate a standard logging operation, and then create thread pool threads that do this work. The benefit of this is the thread pool handles the scheduling of the threads and when they execute, but the down side is that you are not guaranteed FIFO logging with this method since the thread scheduler can arbitrarily choose which thread in the pool to run next.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your leader insists about reinventing the wheel, use slf4j with logback's DBAppender behind an AsyncAppender. It's ready out of the box, it works like a charm.

You should really read about [logback's appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

A full example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928091/asynchronous-dbappender-with-logback).